# C# Regex Match Issues

Tags: c#, regex

I am getting this issue in my code when I am trying to match up a pattern to a string it's returning the Success as false... 
The site I am using to test the expression is http://regexhero.net/tester/

Bit of a background before we go into the code:
I am making this as generic as possible. There are some paths that may develop extra `\`'s along the way so to clear it up I first go through with a regular expression if there are more than two `\`'s in the path that it cleans it up. The problem with this is that some of the paths, since they are coming from servers have four `\`'s in the path name (only two `\`'s regularly but since its C# the compiler wants it as four `\`'s) therefore the second step would be to add an extra two `\`'s to the start of the path to satisfy everything and to make things flow better.

Here is an example of a path I would be working with so you have an idea:

```
\\\\moon\Release_to_Eng\V11\Client
```

Here is my code:

```
//pass over the value of what the user selected into the global variable 
GlobalVars.strPrevVersion = GlobalVars.strDstPath + "\\" + cboVerPath.Text;

//if there are more than two \'s in the path then replace them 
GlobalVars.strPrevVersion = Regex.Replace(GlobalVars.strPrevVersion, @"\\{2,}", "\\");

//check to see if there are two \'s at the begining of the path name 
Match match = Regex.Match(GlobalVars.strPrevVersion, @"^\\\\");

//if there are two \'s in the begining of the path name then add two more.
if (match.Success) << THIS is where it goes wrong the Success returns false even though it should match 
{
  GlobalVars.strPrevVersion = @"\\" + GlobalVars.strPrevVersion;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have \\\\ in your string? It sounds like you have \\ , and it's escaped to \\\\ .

Comment: You're already escaping the backlashes using @. You don't need to add additional backslashes. eg. Regex.Match(GlobalVars.strPrevVersion, @"^\\\\"); is actually checking for 4 backslashes, not 2.

Comment: @Reubz Yes he does. You need to escape backslashes in a RegEx string

Comment: @Reubz the verbatim only deal with .net string escape characters not with Regex's escape chars.

Comment: When I debug things and go through the code the path which should be in C# (since it doubles up the \'s) looks like "\\\\moon\\\\Release_to_Eng\\\\V11\\\\Client" when it should be

Comment: A simple test confirms that `Regex.Match(@"\\helo","^\\\\")` gives a successful match. Are you sure that you're not looking at the input in the debugger, and misinterpreting a single backslash for two? The debugger shows escape sequences on strings so the string `@"\helo"` will appear as `\\helo` in the debugger.

Comment: @spender That's exactly what I want is for it to give a successful match however i'm not sure why its not... I with I could provide a screen shot. And yes I'm already aware of how it will appear in the debugger.

Comment: Why not? A breakpoint at the `if(match.Success)` showing the value `GlobalVars.strPrevVersion` and `match.Success` in the watch panel would be handy.

Comment: The watch panel? I haven't had to provide a screen shot before so how does one go about that?

Comment: In the debugger, right click the value you want to watch (highlight it first if it's a compound statement) and choose "add watch"

Comment: Do you have to use regex? That seems to be unnecessary and adds a lot of complication.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out everyone.

Comment: @user2619395 - Please post your answer as an answer and not as part of the question. You may then accept your answer (in two days) to signal that you've got an answer.

Comment: Simple logic should have told you that your last regex would never match. The previous `Replace` operation replaced all strings of multiple '\' characters with '\', so there's no possible way that searching for `\\` in the very next line of code was ever going to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

you could use TrimStart to ensure the right number of backslashes at the beginning :

```
 String s = @"\\\\\\\\testestestest";
 s = @"\\" + s.TrimStart('\\');
```

will always have the 2 at the beginning.  If I misunderstood your goal, let me know.

Comment: I was wanting it to add 2 more to the beginning of the path so it would have 4 but the thing is there could be a drive instead at the begining of the path therefore I was using regex to check if there were two at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP, [user2619395](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2619395/user2619395):

> Just incase anyone has a future problem with this, I figured out it. What was going on is that the reason why it wasnt matching up is that it was looking at the path in text format and not the format C# sees it as in the debugger. Therefore the path only had one \ meanwhile it was looking for two so it would never work. If that makes any sence.

*(user2619395, feel free to add your own answer. Leave a comment on this post after you've done so and I will delete this post.)*